# SQL Query AND statement not returning correct date based on search results

Tags: mysql

I am a little perplexed why this query doesn't seem to return what I want it to, as if I run both statements individually I get the desired results, I just do not when combined.

````
SELECT * FROM `previous_losses_nbav6_with_date_agg` 
WHERE weekday(`DATE:`) = 1 AND `HOME TEAM:` = 'Denver' OR `AWAY TEAM:` = 'Denver'```
````

I have a pretty basic query, I have a date column that lists each day of the week in the following format: 2022-01-28 00:00:00

If I run a query of either

`` SELECT * FROM `previous_losses_nbav6_with_date_agg` WHERE weekday(`DATE:`) = 1 ``

or

`` SELECT * FROM `previous_losses_nbav6_with_date_agg` WHERE `HOME TEAM:` = 'Denver' OR `AWAY TEAM:` = 'Denver' ``

I get my desired results, what am I doing wrong when trying to combine these statements? I thought of a SQL query as a sequential series of events in a select statement but perhaps that is not true?

Comment: Use parentheses in the `WHERE` clause to specify the desired grouping of `AND` and `OR`.

Comment: Appreciate you! Thank you very much!!